# Restarting Prolog engine from Java using JPL

Tags: java, prolog, jpl

In one java application that uses JPL to interact with Prolog, I want to be able to restart the prolog engine with different settings. As an example, I would like to change from SWI to YAP (I configure which engine to use this with the method `JPL.setNativeLibraryDir` with the path of the right native library I need to use).

So after changing the JPL configuration, I was trying to halt the already running prolog engine in order to restart it again afterwards with `JPL.init()`.

First I took a look to `JPL.halt()`, but the documentation says it is deprecated and the comments in the source code of the method said that it is no-op.

Afterwards, I tried to just launch a query with 'halt', but although I see in the console "YAP execution halted" as expected, my java application is also halted (!).

Is there a way to restart the logic engine using JPL without killing my java application ?

Answer (score 0):

why not using a batch file to run scripts. first you can have /Applications/swi -l your/swi/code and then use halt inside your prolog code so that it halts after execution. You can run your batch file inside java using runtime method.